# Searching through a column in an HTML table and extracting data in a corresponding cell?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

Is there a way to have javascript search through one column in an HTML table and return data in a corresponding cell? For example, in the table below, how would I search through the first column for 'C' and automatically return 'D'?

```
---------
| A | B |
---------
| C | D |
---------
```

P.S.: Sorry for the confusing question, I didn't know how else to ask it.

Comment: have you written any code for this ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. To be less snarky: you should take a look at jQuery.

Comment: with a combo of document.querySelectorAll("tr td:first-child") and the nextElementSibling method, Good luck!

Comment: not nearly enough jQuery here for my liking